# Как узнать какой компонент в фокусе

Tags: android, java

Всем привет.

Как на дроиде узнать какой едит был выделен последним? Задача состоит в том, что бы при нажатии на кнопку данные заносились в выделений едит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getCurrentFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29)

> Calls getCurrentFocus() on the Window of this Activity to return the currently focused view.